# Adding and subtracting from two tables javaDB

Tags: sql, derby, netbeans-8

I have problem on adding and subtracting values from different tables using SQL, adding and subtracting works fine, but it returns an INCORRECT values

here is my query to add the "QUANTITY" from table 1(DELIVERIES table) that is grouped by "CONTAINER_TYPE", the same in TABLE 2 (PULLOUT table), I wanted the sum of the quantity of the first table to be subtracted to the sum of the quantity of the second table. but i get and INCORRECT data.

```html
SELECT
CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_NAME,
DELIVERIES.CONTAINER_TYPE,
COALESCE(SUM(DELIVERIES.QUANTITY), 0) AS TOTAL_DELIVERY,
COALESCE(SUM(PULLOUTS.QUANTITY), 0) AS TOTAL_RETURNS,
COALESCE(SUM(DELIVERIES.QUANTITY), 0) - COALESCE(SUM(PULLOUTS.QUANTITY), 0) AS CUSTOMER_BALANCE
FROM EJPADMIN.CUSTOMER
INNER JOIN DELIVERIES
   ON DELIVERIES.CUSTOMER_ID = CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_ID
LEFT JOIN PULLOUTS
    ON PULLOUTS.DELIVERY_ID = DELIVERIES.DELIVERY_ID
GROUP BY CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_NAME, DELIVERIES.CONTAINER_TYPE
```

guys please help. Thankyou!

DELIVERIES table
PULLOUT table
CUSTOMER TRANSACTION table (incorrect result)

Comment: I suspect you're summing the results of the join, not computing the results of the two separate sums.

Comment: thank you, I already solved my problem by using sub queries